# How can I center a dropdown-menu using Bootstrap 5?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-5

There are built-in classes for Bootstrap that I can add to my dropdown menu,  'dropdown-menu-end' and 'dropdown-menu-start', which are extremely close to what I want to achieve. However, I want the dropdown menu to be centered.

Ref: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/#menu-alignment

The drop-down menu button is centered on the webpage using:

```
.dropdown .btn.dropdown-toggle {
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99;
    bottom: 45px;
    right: 50%;
    transform: translate(50%); 
}
```

So the menu automatically opens upwards because it has no room to open downwards. I would have just added my own CSS that moves the dropdown menu into position, but there's some inline CSS that gets applied to it during runtime from Bootstrap that prevents me from overwriting it.

I've made an example of the issue on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/meeky333/ve98ydkj/5/

Does anyone know what I can do?

P.S. Here is an example of how I want it to look:
[image]

Comment: Please post a [mre] of your code. We can't help you if we can't reproduce the issue and you've not given us enough code to work with in order to do so.

Comment: @AStombaugh thank you, I have added a js fiddle in the question replicating the issue.

Comment: I want the dropdown menu centered horizontally relative to the button. Vertically centered isn't necessary, it just needs to be the same height vertically (just above the button)

Comment: @AStombaugh Either centered relative to the button or centered on the page. They both should equate to the same, so long as I don't move the button right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable static positioning using `data-bs-display="static"` on the button, then adjust the attributes inline as desired. Seems to produce the same result as the previous solution, just minus the external CSS with the !important flag

```css
.buttonContainer {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="buttonContainer">
  <div class="dropup">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-display="static" style="width: 6rem; height: 6rem; border-radius: 50%;" type="button" id="ddl-quick-links" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
           <i class="fa fa-chevron-up fa-2x"></i>
         </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width: 320px; height: max-content; transform: translate(-105px, -5px);" aria-labelledby="quick-links">
      <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item" style="padding: 10px; cursor: pointer;">Add Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item" style="padding: 10px; cursor: pointer;">Add Person</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item" style="padding: 10px; cursor: pointer;">Add User</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item" style="padding: 10px; cursor: pointer;">Add Member</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item" style="padding: 10px; cursor: pointer;">Add Product</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item" style="padding: 10px; cursor: pointer;">Add CSS</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works really well, I hadn't thought to add !important to overwrite the bootstrap css that was applied. Thank you kindly, I will mark this answer as correct.

Comment: No problem, and yeah you'll need `!important` quite a few times if you're trying to customize certain Bootstrap elements. I think it largely pertains to anything script related (in this case, the toggle of the `.show` class).

Comment: So my team has disputed that we shouldn't use !important to override anything. I personally think this is a good exception for using it... But anyway, is there a solution you can think of that doesn't involve using the !important flag?

Comment: @Meeky333 See the updated snippet, I found a way to disable the positioning from the Bootstrap docs and then just added the attributes inline instead of through external CSS. Let me know if that works better for you

Comment: That has been exactly it. This is the attribute I wanted all along. For anyone else that needs this as a reference. Here's the bootstrap 5 docs page https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/#responsive-alignment

Thank you again for your help @AStombaugh